# @Aspect with RMI

Tags: java, spring

I have an application server-client RMI with spring configuration. Now I wont to add method calls logging using @Aspect.

I added in my spring-context.xml:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
<bean id="loggerAspect" class="my.aspect.LoggerAspect" />
```

My `loggerAspect` has defined

```
 @Pointcut("execution(* my.rmi.service.*.*(..))")
```

When i try to run my application i get:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
... 8 more
```

My RMI interface extends Serializable and all classes used in this interface also implements Serializable.

Comment: I would add that my aspect logger works fine in other classes than RMI, and my RMI works fine widouth aspect logger but they don't work together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing Spring AOP proxies is tricky because there are a lot of points of failure.

- For Cglib proxies, the generated class don't exist in the endpoint JVM so you will get a class not found exception when deserializing.
- For JDK proxies the advisor chain should be serializable, so AspectJ style (your problem) and xml aop namespace are discarded too.

However, you still can serialize JDK proxies with a serializable advisor chain.

For example, using an `AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor`

```
<bean id="advisor" class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="expression" value="execution (* test.*.*(..))" />
    <property name="advice">
        <bean class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleTraceInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

will work if all the target objects implements an interface.

Comment: I added this into my spring configuration but I got still the same problem. What else I must change? Could you provide me a simple example?

Comment: Try Disabling loggerAspect and setting log level to TRACE in `org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleTraceInterceptor` to view the traces.